# Determining frame size and other calculations in a paging system

Tags: memory, memory-management, paging, main-method

I just had the following question in an exam and was a bit lost with how to solve it. How would I go about making the requested calculations?

*"A paging system uses 48-bit addresses, each of which specifies 1 byte (B) of memory. The system has a main memory unit of 512MB, and a page size of 16KB. Answer the following questions:*

*a) How many frames does the system memory contain?*

*b) How many bits does the system use to maintain displacements (i.e offsets), and how many bits does the system use to maintain page numbers?"*

For the first part, I converted 512MB into KB (1MB = 1024KB):

512MB = 524288KB

I then divided the main memory unit size by the page size:

524288 / 16 = 32768 frames.

This was my best logical guess as to how to compute the frame size, I could be completely off.

I had no idea where to even start with computing the number of bits to maintain displacements and page numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a) How many frames does the system memory contain?**

Number of frames= Physical Address space / frame size

```
            = 512MB / 16KB
            = 2^29 /2^14
            = 2^15
            = 32K frames
```

**b) How many bits does the system use to maintain displacements (i.e offsets), and how many bits does the system use to maintain page numbers?"**

Number of pages= Logical address space / page size

```
           = 2 ^48 / 2^14
           = 2 ^ 34
           = 16G pages.
```

Number of bits for page number=34

Number of bits for offset= 14 bits i.e. (48-34)